# Performing Numpy Operations on a non uniform, Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'm trying to do a numpy.where() operation on an array that has non-uniform shape. For the sake of illustration, let's say I have (what I'm working with is a lot bigger, but the logic should hold either way):

```
arr = []
for i in range(10):
     arr.append(np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10)))
arr = np.asarray(arr)
```

Let's now say I wanted an array of the indicies which are less than 0.5. If this were a 1D array, I would simply do np.where(arr < 0.5), but what do I do here? I would like it to return a (in this example) 10 dimension array with each row being the list in that dimension of the indicies where the value is less than 0.5.

For instance, if the above array gave:

```
array([array([0.73507637, 0.70327347, 0.31516713, 0.6488219 , 0.66745548,
   0.77378875, 0.89300163, 0.19037781, 0.6201341 ]),
   array([0.76805461, 0.59232101, 0.17830064, 0.94818738, 0.85691762,
   0.44050902, 0.32476772, 0.18193364, 0.90932201]),
   array([0.05859908]), array([0.99033651, 0.66480768, 0.49077243]),
   array([0.93790143, 0.33426562, 0.5848347 , 0.44103201]),
   array([2.62793876e-01, 3.46364865e-01, 7.13963584e-01, 4.77483210e-01,
   1.44562363e-01, 5.84852226e-01, 1.83307197e-04, 9.57584193e-01]),
   array([0.39077418, 0.17571111, 0.57948641, 0.55359104, 0.20058291,
   0.28266329]),
   array([0.0722304 , 0.40004995, 0.43718836, 0.88456605]),
   array([0.71694894, 0.24161113, 0.35506731, 0.08472706, 0.71968264]),
   array([0.68719081, 0.79210537, 0.70492745, 0.73468781, 0.60560161,
   0.90117215, 0.16070244, 0.49769041, 0.16078049])], dtype=object)
```

I would want it to return something like:

```
array([array([2, 7], dtype=int64), array([2, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64),
       array([0], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64),
       array([1, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int64),
       array([0, 1, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
       array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), array([6, 7, 8], dtype=int64)],
      dtype=object)
```

Where I can then use the result to create a paired down arr that only has the elements under 0.5. I don't want to simply omit all elements larger than 0.5 because, in practise, I'll use this selection to cut down various other arrays (of the same shape as arr).

I hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: `[np.where(a< 0.5) for a in arr]`?

Comment: I don't think there is a better answer than @QuangHoang.  Numpy is designed to work quickly on uniformly sized arrays.  If you're planning on doing a lot of calculations on your random numbers, it could be worthwhile to embed it in a 10x10 array.  A separate array could keep track of which entries are actually valid.

Comment: @QuangHoang I was trying to avoid that as it takes so long on the array sizes I'll be using (millions of them to iterate over with millions of entries), but if that's all that works I guess it's what I'll have to do.

Comment: @FrankYellin I'll have to see if it's quicker to use multiple arrays with validation than to do a loop over method. Thanks, all!

Comment: You can always use boolean indexing to mask numpy array. For example `mask = arr < 0.5` and `some_array[mask[i]]` is pretty much equivalent to what I imagine you are trying to do with `np.where`.

Comment: @QuangHoang.  I definitely understand your point.  It's hard to know whether to literally answer the question given, or to suggest an alternative implementation.